# "(An) exactly (the) same": two articles ok?

Tags: articles, redundancy

Does it make sense when two articles are used, for example “An exactly the same”? If the former conveys inspecific/abstract item, then what does the latter do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're asking if we use the phrase: *An exactly the same*?

Not normally. It's not generally grammatical to use an article to introduce an adverb *(exactly),* nor to use two articles to introduce a noun *(same).*

But it could be used for some kind of special effect, as could almost any string of words. A context might be that two people see a woman. One says she's the same woman they saw on the TV news because she robbed a bank:

> A: I'm telling you, she's a completely different woman!
>   B: And *I'm* telling *you:* she's an exactly-the-same woman. Let's catch her!

That's something I can cook up in my imagination as possible. But whether or not it's grammatical depends on a careful definition of grammar.

Comment: Hmm, thanks. I like English because it is so much more free/liberal then Russian :) I mean in Russian no one would even imagine that grammar can be defined (carefully or not). It just exists (and it's very strict) :)